# Database for learning/teaching stored procedures

Tags: database, stored-procedures, stored-functions

What is the best database to start learning stored procedures.

Taking into account that each database has its own syntax. Like Postgresql has **functions**, SyBase, Oracle, MS SQL, DB2 has some sophisticated **procedures**..

Is there is some db, you think is good one to use, let's say, for students to demonstrate the principles, knowing which, the students could jump to some specific database without big problems? Something that stays at the middle of the popular set of dbs.

Comment: That's really, really, a matter of taste, you know.

Comment: students should be able to get sql server (developer) free on [dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) and they could also download the [adventure works](https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587) database, should be pretty easy to get up and running etc. but if multi-platform is important then [mysql](https://www.mysql.com/) with [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 2):

As you know that almost all modern DBMS support stored procedures and vary in syntax. So that's pretty much the personnel choice. But the most easy to use DBMS is MySQL. That can be comparatively more  helpful then Oracle, MSSQL or DB2 especially for new students.